# Creating a "chat bubble" on the iPhone, like Tweetie

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Just curious, did I overlook somewhere in the API to display a chat bubble type image as found in the iPhone's SMS application? There's a few applications out there that use bubbles that look verbatim to the iPhone's and I'm wondering if they're using a native widget or their own image.

This is also seen in the Tweetie application where the content of the tweets are.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest using the stretch method they recommend for button images.

```
[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:13]
```

You can see a working example by downloading [Twitterfon](http://twitterfon.net/)'s source(it's on the FAQ page).  You can see how they code a reusable control for it as well as example images for creating your own bubble.

Edit - Source is no longer available(NDA, possibly)

I put the image up [here](http://drop.io/jibschx).  You should be able to figure out the rest :)

Comment: Jesse, it appears the source is no longer available. Any idea if it has been mirrored anywhere?

Comment: oh wow it is gone.  I imagine it's down because they are starting to use iPhone OS 3.0 and it's under NDA.  I obviously can't re-host their source, but I suggest searching stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth for uses and I put the images in a drop. Link is in my answer.

Comment: What else is needed to display image to full tableview width?

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon_2.png"];
[image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:13];
cell.image = image;

Thanks

Comment: can u please see this link..have to implement this with some modification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181095/message-bubbles-for-ios-with-avtar-image-avtar-name-and-timestamp-on-each-buble

Answer (score 15):

There is a video tutorial showing Jabs method here http://vimeo.com/8718829 it includes bubble graphics in many colours. Also the the twitterfon source is here
https://github.com/jimpick/twitterfon

(these should be comments to jabs answer but I don't have high enough rating to comment)

Comment: The video tutorial on Vimeo is awesome !

Answer (score 6):

You need to use your own images, and Apple recommends using 9 UIImageViews (3 rows of 3) (Top Left Corner, Top Middle, Top Right Corner, Middle Left Side, Middle, Middle Right Side, Bottom Left Corner, Bottom Middle, Bottom Right Corner)

Comment: thanks kdb. any chance you can point me in the right direction for where apple makes these recommendations?

Comment: It was at WWDC (should be in one of the videos)

Comment: That's not really necessary. You can just use -[UIImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:] to specify your stretchable area. See the UIImage docs for more info.

Comment: There is no way that Tweetie (or the SMS app) is using 9 separate UIViews per chat message. The performance would be horrid. Use the method Mike suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Read the code in UICatalog's ButtonsViewController.m: "+buttonWithTitle:" which creates a stretchable button from one image, which is the same case for creating a chat bubble.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/acaniChat). It's the best open source version of the iPhone Messages app. It uses Core Data and will soon use WebSockets.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this today from one of my RSS feeds.

Its a bunch of UI elements re-created in illustrator

Notably they have the chat bubbles.  You might be able to use them as a start for images to do what kdbdallas is saying.

http://www.mercuryintermedia.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/iphone-ui-vector-elements

Hope this helps.

chris.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to make UILabels with stretchable image background. If you are wanting to put images in the bubble you'll have to do some masking to get it to look like Apple's. Check out the [BubbleThingie](https://github.com/tkirby/BubbleThingie/blob/master/README.md) sample code for example of how to do the image masking. It also has example of how to do the text bubbles using a UIButton or UILabel.

[image]

Comment: cn u please see this link..have to implement this with some modification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181095/message-bubbles-for-ios-with-avtar-image-avtar-name-and-timestamp-on-each-buble

Answer (score 1):

Many of our applications have chat or messaging facility, and many of the clients are asking to build chat "similar to that iPhone's SMS chat, with bubbles".

Unfortunately, Cocoa SDK does not provide convenient and easy way to display chat bubbles, and numerous code snippets that we've googled were not perfect either - some of them were simply ugly, some displayed bubbles of the same size regardless of text length, some did not alter bubble width, some were good, but barely customizable, etc.

Eventually, Alex - our leading iOS architect (who also happens to be the CTO at Stex) - went ahead and wrote this code from scratch. Main features are:

- easily (really easily!) customizable and embeddable. The code is based on the UITableView subclassing approach, so once you need to add the chat facility to the app - consider this as simply adding the UITableView, where each cell is a messag
- easily customizable bubble's color and style - there's 2 pictures, that can be easily tweaked in Photoshop
- time grouping
- flexible bubble height and witdh

The code can be downloaded from GitHub, https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView

Comment: As I suggested in your other answer, I've tried to flesh this out by moving the content from your linked blog post into this answer, including a direct link to your GitHub project. You might still want to edit this to better direct it at this audience, but this is preferred over just linking to a blog post.