# Implement view like standard iPhone SMS-chat bubbles view

Tags: iphone

Does anybody know how to implement such view, any tutorials, code examples, ideas.

Other good example of such view is Tweetie application that is on top of social networking appstore applications. See first screenshot of that app on appstore.

I appreciate any ideas on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer, with example code, direct from the source (the creator of Tweetie): http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/

From the blog post: "The technique is extensible to pretty much any style cell you need - I use the same thing in Tweetie and draw the chat bubble, text, and avatar all together into a single view."  You can use `- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight` to create a stretchable chat bubble to put behind each cell in your table view

Comment: Actually, all he describes in that post is how to do fast scrolling using a UITableView.  The message bubble layout code is not in the source he provides, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Fix the link please, it seems broken now

Comment: Link broken and cannot be accessible.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Acani Chats](https://github.com/acani/Chats).

It uses an [identical background image for the UITextView](http://www.mercuryintermedia.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/iphone-ui-vector-elements).

Comment: Hi! there exists a tuto to  use AcaniChat? I tryed to compile the project without lucky...

Comment: @doxsi you need the latest version of Xcode to compile it.

Comment: @doxsi no, you need the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

There are some thoughts on this here:

[Creating a “chat bubble” user experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351602/creating-a-chat-bubble-user-experience)

Be sure to read the comments on the answers as well!

Answer (score 2):

Search for [jsqmessagesviewcontroller](http://www.jessesquires.com/JSQMessagesViewController/), it's a good library.

Comment: Good for learning the concepts to design bubbles at least from the code structure although rigid

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they're basically table-views with cells of different heights that are custom-drawn. You can do a lot by supplying your own background and content view's in a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [BubbleThingie](https://github.com/tkirby/BubbleThingie/blob/master/README.md) sample code for example of how to do image bubbles with masking. It also has example of how to do the text bubbles using a UIButton or UILabel.

[image]