# Stretch PNGs smoothly in Cocoa AppKit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663435/implement-view-like-standard-iphone-sms-chat-bubbles-view) it shows how to use UIKit's

```
-(UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

to stretch a PNG easily, e.g when inserting text in an iChat like bubble.  I would like to do the same on regular AppKit/Cocoa/desktop app using CoreGraphics or some NSImage related API but couldn't find an equivalent method.  Does anybody know how to do this in AppKit?

Comment: NSDrawThreePartImage works nicely, thanks Peter, however you have to create 3 pngs.  Not a huge deal but I do notice that a lot of apps have one png bubble as a resource that they stretch somehow, so leaving this open for a little while longer in case anybody knows a single png technique.

Comment: You can use the technique Ben Gottlieb mentions to split the image into three parts. Create a new, empty image for each part, then draw the relevant section of the whole image into each part image.

Comment: Alternatively, use [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity) for the whole image, and use its Factories and Slices features to generate three PNGs from the one Opacity document.

Comment: Of course, thanks so much Peter!  Works perfectly.

Comment: You could also cut the image into the 9 images in code: https://gist.github.com/1465424

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`NSDrawThreePartImage`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDrawThreePartImage) or [`NSDrawNinePartImage`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSDrawNinePartImage).

Comment: @ErikAigner: Not necessarily manually. Several graphics editors provide “slice” features for automatically sectioning the image.

Answer (score 2):

Just use -[NSImage drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:], and pass NSZeroRect as the fromRect; parameter.

Comment: Does this work to smoothy stretch/tile an image along one axis?  I tried this with a png and it didn't work, it just stretched all the pixels.  I know there must be some way to do this with one png because I notice that a lot of apps have single pngs in their resources.  NSDrawThreePartImage did work however.

Comment: Btw, I called this as follows:
     [speechBubbleImage drawInRect:speechBubbleRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function i whipped up that takes 1 image, and stretches just the middle...

[image]

```
-(NSImage *)image:(NSImage *)image leftCapWidth:(float)leftWidth middleWidth:(float)middleWidth rightCapWidth:(float)rightWidth {

    // Calculate the new images dimensions
    float imageWidth = leftWidth + middleWidth + rightWidth;
    float imageHeight = image.size.height;

    // Generate the left image
    NSRect rectLeft = NSMakeRect(0, 0, leftWidth, imageHeight);
    NSImage *imageLeft = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rectLeft.size];
    if (imageLeft.size.width > 0) {
        [imageLeft lockFocus];
        [image drawInRect:rectLeft fromRect:rectLeft operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [imageLeft unlockFocus];
    }

    // Generate the middle image
    NSRect rectMiddle = NSMakeRect(0, 0, image.size.width - (rightWidth + leftWidth), imageHeight);
    NSImage *imageMiddle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rectMiddle.size];
    if (imageMiddle.size.width > 0) {
        [imageMiddle lockFocus];
        [image drawInRect:rectMiddle fromRect:NSMakeRect(leftWidth, 0, rectMiddle.size.width, imageHeight) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [imageMiddle unlockFocus];
    }

    // Generate the right image
    NSRect rectRight = NSMakeRect(0, 0, rightWidth, imageHeight);
    NSImage *imageRight = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rectRight.size];
    if (imageRight.size.width > 0) {
        [imageRight lockFocus];
        [image drawInRect:rectRight fromRect:NSMakeRect(image.size.width - rightWidth, 0, rightWidth, imageHeight) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
        [imageRight unlockFocus];
    }

    // Combine the images
    NSImage *newImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(imageWidth,  imageHeight)] autorelease];
    if (newImage.size.width > 0) {
        [newImage lockFocus];
        NSDrawThreePartImage(NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight), imageLeft, imageMiddle, imageRight, NO, NSCompositeSourceOver, 1, NO); 
        [newImage unlockFocus];
    }

    // Release the images and return the new image
    [imageLeft release];
    [imageMiddle release];
    [imageRight release];

    return newImage;
}
```