# How to create bubbble message box similar to iPhone buildin SMS app?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

How to create bubbble message box similar to iPhone buildin SMS app?

I'm trying to create a table cells with a bubble message box, similar to the iPhone SMS app or iChat.

Anybody have example code I can refer to?

Comment: I found this old threads discussing this topic, http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg12829.html.
WebView seems like a good way to implement this but I am not sure if the performance is ideal.

Comment: I found more earlier threads on this very topic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663435/implement-view-like-standard-iphone-sms-chat-bubbles-view/663875

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImage`'s can have borders at the sides and bottom that don't resize as the image is stretched.

The [leftCapWidth](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/leftCapWidth) and [topCapHeight](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/topCapHeight) are the 2 properties you need to modify to achieve this.

Then create a UIImageView (using the image) of the necessary size behind your text.

Comment: Thanks!
I also found earlier question asked on this same topic,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351602/creating-a-chat-bubble-on-the-iphone-like-tweetie