# iphone messages app. How can I build something similar?

Tags: iphone, sms, implementation, message

I want to build some thing very similar to the iphone messages app that comes by default on the iphone. I am not sure of what UI elements that i should be using to build the conversation view of the messages app.

How are the balloons created and how are they placed in positions. What UI elements are used to create the balloons ?

I am pretty new to the iphone app development

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351602/creating-a-chat-bubble-on-the-iphone-like-tweetie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also say it's a UITableView with custom-drawn cells. A few CGGradients and a CALayer with rounded corners can get you a long way.

Answer (score 0):

If I had my guess, I'd say they are very custom UITableViewCells, inside of course a UITableView.

I think you'd need custom graphics to represent the balloons - I mean you generate them programmatically, but that seems rather difficult, opposed to having the art assets.

I think creating an app like that would be a challenge, but it'd be fun.

Answer (score 0):

A side note: If you plan to submit this to the app store don't copy the Messages app's text bubbles too closely. I think it was in the IM+ app where Apple rejected it because they used the same color and identical look as Apple's app. They had to basically strip the color so that all bubbles are the same, instead of 1 color for your text and another for the other person's.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat). It's the best open source version of the iPhone Messages app. It uses Core Data and will soon use WebSockets.